# How to avoid copying all the docker context directory?

Tags: docker

I want to build a docker image that is based on files from several locations within the repository
(theres a project directory for each service, and some files needed from shared directories)

The full repository if pretty large, so using the repository root as context slows things down.

But using the service directory is also problematic, as it's impossible to copy files to the docker image from outside the repository

my current solution is to copy all files to a "staging" directory, but i'm looking for something cleaner and faster

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

Comment: from what I know docker ignore is in the context library, and can't be loaded from a different location like docker file. which makes it problematic if you need a different docker ignore for each docker image

Comment: Yes, looks like you can only have 1 `.dockerignore` per context. If you have different Dockerfiles with same context but want different `.dockerignore`, I don't think it's possible.